# Add htaccess for phpMyAdmin installed in /usr/share/?

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu-10.10, apache-2.2

Installed phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 10.10, running apache2.  phpMyAdmin resides in /usr/share/, and is accessible because there is alias in apache2.

I'd like to add an .htaccess file for it, but I am unsure of where to place it, or if I should use some other method to prevent the site from being accessed by someone other than me (with password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's installed in /usr/share/phpmyadmin, you can put the approrpriate .htaccess in /usr/share/phpmysadmin.

That being said, HTTP auth isn't exactly fool-proof if that's what you're looking to use .htaccess for, so I'd instead recommend restricting by IP.

If however your intent is to use http-auth anyway, you can configure phpmyadmin's config.inc.php and set the `auth_type` to `http`

I personally would recommend cookie-based auth instead, combined with a somewhat restrictive .htaccess to keep out people you don't want seeing it.